# HTML/CSS Media Query

Tags: html, css

I have referenced the viewport meta tag and stylesheet link correctly but still my media query doesn't work.

All CSS style works with the exception of the media query styling.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the css as well

Comment: where write your media query.

Comment: Hi Richard, welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a couple of guidelines that could be applied when asking questions, so please make sure to check them out. In order for us to start helping you out on your question, could you please provide us with a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

If you have written the Media Query in the main.css it won't override the default Media Queries of bootstrap and rest of the stylesheets, because you need to call your main.css after all the default stylesheets. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> and write this type:-

for max-width:- @media (max-width:767px) {code here}

for min-width and max-width:- @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {code here}